# trying to show and hide columns datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Due to the new version of datatables I'm using, my show hide functionality for columns is broken

```
$("a.hideLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this);
    var columnIndex = $link.attr("href");
    $("#hiddenCols").append('<a class="showLink" href="' + columnIndex + '">' + $link.attr("title") + '</a>');
    $dTable.column(columnIndex).visible(false);
});

$(document).on('click','a.showLink',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this);
    var columnIndex = $link.attr("href");
    $dTable.column(columnIndex).visible(true);
    //$dTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    $link.remove();
});
```

I'm trying to change it, but unable to fix it, any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the button "colVis" ?

Comment: where exactly, i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

When you create your datatables you have all your options (pagination, scrollY, scrollX,.....). In your option "buttons", you should add 'colvis'. Don't forget to add the correct cdn . When you will click on this button you can choose the columns you want to hide or show.
https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/colvis.html